# get request returning empty json with valid parameter

Tags: php, json, rest, get

so i have a database of Affiliates in the phpmyadmin of a site and i made a get api to get an specific affiliate given the id number, now i can connect and i make the call, but everytime i only get an empty json example

> ["","","","","",""]

doesnt matter if the id number is a valid one, an invalid one or even a letter, thats what i get every time

now here is my code for the connection

```
 <?php 
 header( 'Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8' );


 function ejecutarSQLCommand($commando){

 $mysqli = new mysqli("ip", "user", "pass","database");

 /* check connection */
 if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
 printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
 exit();
 }

 if ( $mysqli->multi_query($commando)) {
    if ($resultset = $mysqli->store_result()) {
       while ($row = $resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

       }
        $resultset->free();
     }


}



$mysqli->close();
}

function getSQLResultSet($commando){


  $mysqli = new mysqli("ip", "user", "pass", "database");
  /* check connection */
  if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
  }

if ( $mysqli->multi_query($commando)) {
    return $mysqli->store_result();




}



$mysqli->close();
}


?>
```

and here is the request file

```
<?php
include('function.php');
$id=$_GET["ID"];


if($resultset=getSQLResultSet("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ID='$id'")){
    while ($row = $resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
        echo json_encode($row);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I would var_dump() the $row to make sure you have something. Each row is going to be a separate json object Then use prepared statements to protect your db http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @JasonK i only get on affiliate(row at a time)

also i dont seem to be getting anything   

array(5) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" } null

            any idea what can i do about it?

Answer (score 0):

I made more realistic code. The next step would be making this into a class.

The prepare in stead of a query will protect against SQL injection also data with quotes in it.

```
index.php

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

include('function.php');

$id=$_GET["ID"];

dbConnect();
$rows = getSQLResultSet($id);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

dbClose();

```
function.php

<?php
//
// not sure if this is needed for returning json
//
header( 'Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8' );

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
function  dbConnect(){
    //
    // You should be gettng the db connect info from a source out side the webservers reach.
    //
    // read a ini file or imclude a file
    //

    $ip     = '127.0.0.1';
    $user = 'test';
    $pass = 'test12';
    $db     = 'test';

    $GLOBALS['mysqlI'] = new mysqli($ip, $user, $pass, $db);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_errno());
        exit();
    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function dbClose(){
    $GLOBALS['mysqlI']->close();
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function getSQLResultSet($id){
    $stmt = $GLOBALS['mysqlI']->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE ID = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $ret[] = $row;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: now i am just getting some error notices, just so you know, DNI, is the name of my ID
Notice: Undefined index: DNI in location/query.php on line 8

Notice: Use of undefined constant DNI - assumed 'DNI' in location/function.php on line 35

Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in location/function.php on line 35